# Laravel Lumen routes not loading

Tags: laravel, docker, apache2, lumen

Please, I have deployed a Lumen application in a docker container, running Ubuntu and Apache 2.4 but all requests I make to the app returns a 404 except for the root.

Here are some things That I have done from reading other posts...

1. Enable Module rewrite by running `a2enmod rewrite`
2. Adding `Require all granted` and `AllowOverride All` to the Directory directive in my conf files

Here is the structure of my 000-default.conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/public

        <Directory /var/www/public>
                Require all granted
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Lastly, when I run `php artisan route:list` all I see is the following...

`+------+------+------------+------------+---------+------------+
| Verb | Path | NamedRoute | Controller | Action  | Middleware |
+------+------+------------+------------+---------+------------+
| GET  | /    |            | None       | Closure |            |
+------+------+------------+------------+---------+------------+`

Please, What do I have to do to get this to work?

**EDIT:** Here is my `.htaccess` file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Apache seems to discard the Authorization header if it is not a
    # base64 encoded user/pass combo
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
    RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**EDIT 2:** Routes

```
$api = $app->make(Dingo\Api\Routing\Router::class);

$api->version('v1', [], function () use ($api) {

    $api->get('/', function () {
        return json_encode("Vendors API root");
    });

    $api->group(['prefix' => 'vendors', 'namespace' => 'App\Api\v1\Controllers'], function () use ($api) {

        // Vendor API Endpoints
        $api->get('/list', 'VendorController@listVendors');
        $api->get('/{id}/get', 'VendorController@getVendor');
        $api->post('/add', 'VendorController@addVendor');
    });

});
```

Comment: > I have deployed a Lumen application in a docker container
How? Please give some information on how you built and ran the Docker container.

Comment: docker doesn't seem to be the major issue in this... I think the problem is with my apache configuration. Anyway, I have a `docker-compose` and a `DockerFile` configured to install Apache, push my code to Digital Ocean, and run `docker-compose up --build`

Comment: Sure, but the configuration is dependent on where the code ends up in the container. You also mention running `a2enmod rewrite` and if you happened to be running this command and then copying configuration in a `Dockerfile`, there would be a possibility of overwriting the result of this command (since both change configuration files). Listing the contents of the files might also be helpful as this application sounds like it might be dependent on a `.htaccess` file as well.